# Finding a string and replacing?

Tags: php, replace

Is it possible to find `MUSECMS_WIDGET(NAMEOFWIDGETHERE);` and get the `NAMEOFWIDGETHERE`? And then replace the `MUSECMS_WIDGET(NAMEOFWIDGETHERE);` with 
`<!--NAMEOFWIDGETHERE--!>`?

Comment: So you are asking to find `NAMEOFDIDGETHERE` in a string `MUSECMS_WIDGET(NAMEOFWIDGETHERE);` and replace it with dot? (`.`)?

Comment: It's okay - I found a way around it, register all widget names in a database, then check for each widget in the text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simple example:

```
$var = str_replace("NAMEOFWIDGETHERE", "Your Replacement", $subject);
```

The $subject is your original String.

Answer (score 2):

Please consider:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

If you don't know about regular expressions please read up on them here:

http://www.zytrax.com/tech/web/regex.htm